# In JavaScript how do I extract my display assignment operations into two functions that each take in an element parameter?

Tags: javascript, function

I have been asked to refactor my Javascript code into multiple functions(where each function does one thing) and I am stuck on what to do.  I need my display assignment operations to be two separate functions and all values should be passed into functions as arguments/parameters, so no global variables.  I am not even sure where to start,  I feel like this should be easy but I am racking my brain here.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body onload="changeChooser()">
    <h1>Monster Mash</h1>
    <p>Pick your favorite monster from the dropdown!</p>
    <select id="monsterChooser" onchange="changeChooser();">
        <option value="monsterContent">Monsters</option>
        <option value="frankContent">Frankenstein</option>
        <option value="draculaContent">Dracula</option>
        <option value="wolfmanContent">Wolfman</option>
        <option value="mummyContent">Mummy</option>
        <option value="piggyContent">I hate monsters</option>
        </select>
    <div id="monsterContent">
        <h2>Monster Madness</h2>
        <img src="images/monsters.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="frankContent">
        <h2>Frankenstein</h2>
        <img src="images/frankenstein.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="draculaContent">
        <h2>Dracula</h2>
        <img src="images/dracula.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="wolfmanContent">
        <h2>Wolfman</h2>
        <img src="images/wolfman.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="mummyContent">
        <h2>Mummy</h2>
        <img src="images/mummy.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="piggyContent">
        <h2>FINE!</h2>
        <p>Here is a little piggy eating ice cream!</p>
        <img src="images/piggy.jpg">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
<script>
    function changeChooser() {
        console.log("gotChange");
        var chooser = document.getElementById("monsterChooser");
        var options = chooser.options;
        var counter = 0;

        while (counter < options.length) {
            if (options[counter].selected) {
                document.getElementById(options[counter].value).style.display = "";
            } else {
                document.getElementById(options[counter].value).style.display = "none";
            }
            counter = counter + 1;
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start with refactoring is to see which parts of your code are using same/similar references or performing similar work. I would extract the 2 lines that change the `display` property into a separate function:

```
<script>
  function changeChooser() {
    var chooser = document.getElementById("monsterChooser");

    for (var i = 0; i < chooser.options.length; i++) {
      var id = chooser.options[counter].value;

      if (chooser.options[i].selected) {
        changeDisplayById(id, '');
      } else {
        changeDisplayById(id, 'none');
      }
    }

  }

  function changeDisplayById(id, display) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = display;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make these improvements (but there are several good alternative solutions):

- Use strict mode to benefit from language improvements and stricter checks
- Bind handlers in code with `addEventListener` instead of using HTML attributes for this
- Use a function (it could be the DOMContentLoaded event handler) to create a scope for all your local variables, if any
- Browsers create (global) variables anyway for all elements that have an ID attribute. You could use those instead of performing a lookup with `getElementById`
- You can use a CSS selector to find all the `div` elements that need to be shown/hidden, and you could do that lookup only once and store the result

```js
"use strict";
// Preferrably bind event handlers in code, not in HTML attributes:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Put all code in this closure, so new variables (if any) are local

    // Only query the content DIV elements once, using a CSS selector 
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[id*=Content]');
    
    changeChooser();
    // Global variables are automatically created for all elements with an ID: use them
    monsterChooser.addEventListener('change', changeChooser);

    function changeChooser() {
        // Apply hideElement to all content divs
        Array.from(divs, hideElement);
        // Show the specific div:
        showElement(document.getElementById(monsterChooser.value));
    }

    function hideElement(elem) {
        elem.style.display = "none";
    }
    function showElement(elem) {
        elem.style.display = "";
    }
});
```

```html
<h1>Monster Mash</h1>
<p>Pick your favorite monster from the dropdown!</p>
<select id="monsterChooser">
    <option value="monsterContent">Monsters</option>
    <option value="frankContent">Frankenstein</option>
    <option value="draculaContent">Dracula</option>
    <option value="wolfmanContent">Wolfman</option>
    <option value="mummyContent">Mummy</option>
    <option value="piggyContent">I hate monsters</option>
    </select>
<div id="monsterContent">
    <h2>Monster Madness</h2>
    <img src="images/monsters.jpg">
</div>
<div id="frankContent">
    <h2>Frankenstein</h2>
    <img src="images/frankenstein.jpg">
</div>
<div id="draculaContent">
    <h2>Dracula</h2>
    <img src="images/dracula.jpg">
</div>
<div id="wolfmanContent">
    <h2>Wolfman</h2>
    <img src="images/wolfman.jpg">
</div>
<div id="mummyContent">
    <h2>Mummy</h2>
    <img src="images/mummy.jpg">
</div>
<div id="piggyContent">
    <h2>FINE!</h2>
    <p>Here is a little piggy eating ice cream!</p>
    <img src="images/piggy.jpg">
</div>
```